# Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am experiencing a Javascript runtime error, when I click a save button on my web form, that appears to be related to an Ajax TabPanel.  The error message is “Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method”.  The reason I say I believe it is related to the TabPanel is because the JavaScript function that is throwing the error is “Sys$UI$DomEvent$_removeHandler(element, eventName, handler)” and the some of the properties of the parameter “element” reference my TabPanel.  It’s strange that I am seeing this error now because the only thing I really changed was upgrading to the latest AjaxControlToolkit (Version 15.1.1.100).  Previously I was not getting this error.  My entire form is wrapped in a single UpdatePanel and has always been this way.  I also have two ModalPopupExtenders on this page which I have heard can cause this error if the OK or Cancel controls for the Popup are inside the update panel which they are, but have never caused an issue previously.

The only thing I found in my web searching that was not specifically related to ModalPopupExtenders that I tried was setting the ScriptManager ScriptMode tag to "Release"

The markup for this webform is pretty long so I am only posting that which is specific to the TabContainer and TabPanel.  Please forgive the inline CSS.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE (5/28/2015)**

I decided to roll back the AjaxControlToolkit to the previous version I was using (version 4.1.7.1213) and the error message / problem is no longer happening.  I would like to be able to use the latest Ajax library but need to figure out how to fix the error first.

Also, I found in another search this morning that this may be a known bug in the version of the toolkit I mentioned as reference here [Tab Container Bug](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27775).  It appears that a fix is already in place for the upcoming version 15.3.  You have to read through some of the comments to see where others have seen the error I am referring to above.  I guess I will stick with the old version until I know for sure this is fixed!

```
    <asp:Panel ID="CollapsiblePNL" class="collapsePanel" runat="server" style="height:0px; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px">    
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoPostBack="True" OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged" ActiveTabIndex="1" >

        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="AddFilesTabPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Add Files">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" Width="100%" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="emptyMyAjaxFileUpload" MaximumNumberOfFiles="0" AllowedFileTypes="" OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart"  />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

       <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="AttachedFilesTabPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Attached Files">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="float: left; clear:left; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Current Attached Files" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; clear:left; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Rows="10" Width="400px"></asp:ListBox>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left">
                    <div style="float: left; vertical-align: middle; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
                        <asp:Button ID="RemoveFileBTN" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirmation();" OnClick="RemoveFileBTN_Click" Width="99px"/>  
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; clear:left; vertical-align: middle;  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
                        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAllFilesBTN" runat="server" Text="Remove All"  OnClientClick="return confirmation();" OnClick="RemoveAllFilesBTN_Click" Width="99px" />  
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; clear:left; vertical-align: middle; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
                        <asp:Button ID="OpenBTN" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="OpenBTN_Click" Width="99px"/>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</asp:Panel>
```